# How to lose weight

Tags: weight-loss

I am an boy of age 17, weight 92KG (200 lbs) and height 5'6" these are the exercises I perform currently

1-25 knee pushups (5 sets 5 reps)

2-5 min on the spot running(1 min Marching 30 sec jogging and running).

3- Stretching

4- 50 cupboard pushups

Cannot control my diet (but only homemade food no junk food either)

Should I be adding any exercises?if yes then which ones

Comment: Can you portion control your diet?

Comment: Will try to do soo

Answer (score 0):

Your question is really unclear.
It depends on whether you are going for fat loss, or body building, or in general physical fitness.
Since your weight/height ratio is a bit high I am assuming you are going for fat loss.
If that is the case you should definitely incorporate a 3 Km run in your exercise schedule which can later be scaled up to a 5 Km run and so on. Be sure to stretch before you run though.
I would also recommend scaling up the push ups to a minimum of 50, 5 sets of 10 pushups

Comment: The 25 pushups are in it self at my peak level and I am extremely unwilling to run outside so how long should I be doing at at one spot? And I want to burn fat and gain light muscles.

Comment: @RazaHassan There are many more cardio options than running outside.  You can do jumping jacks in your bedroom, run in place in your living room, use a treadmill, ride a bike, swim, walk... etc.  It is easy to find excuses but excuses will not help you burn fat and gain muscles.

Comment: Well I have incorporated a 3km run in my workout I perform it at night but it takes me about 30 minutes . Is this rate ok?

Answer (score 0):

For your goals, you need to lose fat and that means only two things...

1. More cardio exercise
2. Less calorie consumption

The pushups are ok if you feel you need some upper body strength but in as so far as your stated goals are concerned, they do absolutely nothing towards losing fat.

You say that you cannot control your diet.  I cannot see how that is possible.  Everyone can control their diet.  If you cannot change the actual food you are eating because someone else is cooking it, then you can at least reduce the portions of the food you eat and that will reduce your calorie consumption.

Incorporate some cardio into your workout.  Start with a nice 30 minute walk at least three times a week.  After a couple of weeks, speed up the pace and keep doing that until you feel comfortable running for 30 minutes three times a week.  By that time, you will be lean and healthy and you can move on to heavier training if you want to.

Answer (score 0):

I would challenge the premise of your question. Is your goal to lose weight or to be healthy? Exercise is a small portion of weight loss. Diet is the biggest factor. Focus on the quality of the food you eat more so than the quantity. You do need a calorie deficit to lose weight, but you could get that on of those fad diets like the cookie diet, etc... You would be in a calorie deficit but you wouldn't be healthy.

Comment: I think the OP has stated that he cannot do anything about the diet.  Given that he has stated that he is 17 it is possible that someone else (maybe his mother) cooks and he has to eat what she makes.  Portion control along with cardio would be his best bet to lose weight and be healthy.

Comment: That is true MikeV, but I'm wondering if he asks his mom to cook some specific meals to be more healthy if it would be doable? Nothing crazy, just stuff like the Kroger brand Simple Truth meat products.

Comment: I know what you mean.  I also found it kind of strange that he could not suggest better foods or request them but well... we can only answer based on what the OP says.